# UIView animation full circle rotation reverse with UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut

Tags: ios, animation, uiview

```
           [UIView animateWithDuration:3 delay:0 options:( UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut |
                                                       UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat |
                                                       UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction) animations:^{
            self.animatedImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.animatedImageView.transform, M_PI);
        } completion:^(BOOL finished){}];
```

How can this animation be a full circle rotation while still accelerating and deaccelerating. if I use 2 * M_PI the animation is not moving.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think this should work for you:

```
- (IBAction)rotate:(UIButton *)sender {

    CABasicAnimation *rotationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
    rotationAnimation.toValue = @(M_PI * 2.0);
    rotationAnimation.duration = 1;
    rotationAnimation.autoreverses = YES;
    rotationAnimation.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
    rotationAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    [self.iv.layer addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:@"rotationAnimation"];
}
```

Comment: rotationAnimation.repeatCount = 0;
I wanted for one time clock and anti clock animation hence i kept repeat count = 0. So with this I give animation to my circle full clock and full anti clock wise but once.

Answer (score 5):

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:3 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
            self.animatedImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.animatedImageView.transform, M_PI);
        } completion:^(BOOL finished){

        [UIView animateWithDuration:3 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
        self.animatedImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.animatedImageView.transform, (2*M_PI)-0.001); //  -0.001 will do the right way
    } completion:^(BOOL finished){}];


}];
```

Comment: When i try the code it still stops after the first half rotation. So the code in the completion block doesnt seem to have an effect. I would also like the animation to auto reverse and to repeat it self.

Comment: do another UIView animation in completion handler and there you do your other half M_PI rotation.

Answer (score 1):

This should work. You can change animation type : `UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight`.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:(UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight)
                       forView:Your_View cache:YES];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```